# Why does the regex in find not return any results?

Tags: linux, regex

The command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[a-z0-9\-\_\.]+\.(gz|deb)/' -exec echo {} \;
```

yields no results in a directory containing the following files:

1. `google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb`
2. `rkhunter-1.4.2.tar.gz`

although, when testing the regular expression `[a-z0-9\-\_\.]+\.(gz|deb)` on sites such as [RegExr](http://regexr.com/), it matches these names.

Why does the `find` not return any results?

Comment: Do you have any such file in your current directory? Could you show their names?

Comment: Why use `-exec echo {} \;`?   That's what `-print` is for.

Comment: @Scott - The reason is because i'll be substituting it with a command such as `mv`

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - Thanks and yes there are files in the directory. A sample of them has been provided in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. You ended your regex string with `/`. 
   Filenames do not end with `/`.
2. Apparently [RegExr](http://regexr.com) has a bug:
   to include a literal dash (**`-`**) in a regex bracket expression,
   it must be the first character, immediately after the `[`
   (or after the initial `^`, if any),
   or the last character, immediately before the `]`. 
   You are not allowed to stick it in the middle,
   not even with a `\` in front of it.

But also:

3. `^`, **`-`**, `[` and `]` are the only individual characters
   that are special in a regex bracket expression;
   you do not need to escape **`.`** —
   and there’s no reason at all to escape `_`.

So your regex could/should be `.*/[-a-z0-9_.]+\.(gz|deb)`.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't aware that `-` had  to be either defined at the start or the end of the expression. Does `.` follow the same premise?

Comment: Quite the opposite — inside `[`…`]`, a **`.`** is just an ordinary character, like a letter or a digit (or `!`, `@`, `#`, etc…, and even `$` and `*`) and can appear anywhere, without needing to be escaped.  I left it at the end of the bracket expression because that’s where you had it.  So `.*/[a-z0-9_.-]+\.(gz|deb)` would also work.